# snmpbulkwalk error with opensips mibs

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, opensips

I have configured `SNMP` support with `Opensips` but i am getting following error when i am running `snmpbulkwalk`

I did following too

```
apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
master          agentx
rocommunity  voip
syslocation  "Virtual DataCenter"
syscontact  abc@gmail.com
```

I also copied all Opensips MIBS file into /usr/share/snmp/mibs

Error:

```
root@opensip:~# snmpbulkwalk -O s -v 2c -c  voip 127.0.0.1 OPENSER-SIP-COMMON-MIB::openserSIPCommonObjects
    MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
    Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
    Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
    Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-DLMOD-MIB
    Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB
    Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB
    Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB)
    Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB)
    Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB)
    Unlinked OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdavis ::= { enterprises 2021 }
    Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB
    Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-DLMOD-MIB)
    Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-DLMOD-MIB)
    Unlinked OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
    ...
    ...
    Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 28 of /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegExCompilation ::= { logMatchEntry 101 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchErrorFlag ::= { logMatchEntry 100 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCycle ::= { logMatchEntry 11 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCount ::= { logMatchEntry 10 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 9 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCount ::= { logMatchEntry 8 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 7 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCount ::= { logMatchEntry 6 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 5 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegEx ::= { logMatchEntry 4 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchFilename ::= { logMatchEntry 3 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchName ::= { logMatchEntry 2 }
    Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchIndex ::= { logMatchEntry 1 }
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the UCD-SNMP-MIB. I'm not familiar with opensips. Does it require you use the older UCD-SNMP rather than NET-SNMP?

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question.